# defining colors for a rast object

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a rast object which needs to be exported with a defined color style. The values are not integers. When I try to define the coltab the values are automatically corrected to integers.

I create a raster:

```r
r <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=c(0.1,0.5,0.7,1,1.4,1.7))
plot(r)
```

[image: plot of the raster]

I create a data frame with values and respective colors:

```r
coltb <- data.frame(value=c(0.1,0.5,0.7,1,1.4,1.7), col=rainbow(6, end=.9))

> coltb
  value     col
1   0.1 #FF0000
2   0.5 #EBFF00
3   0.7 #00FF29
4   1.0 #00C2FF
5   1.4 #5200FF
6   1.7 #FF0099
```

I assign it to the raster and plot it:

```r
coltab(r) <- coltb
plot(r)
```

[image: plot of the raster with the assigned coltab]

If I check the coltab, the values are transformed in integers:

```r
> coltab(r)
[[1]]
  values red green blue alpha
1      0 255     0    0   255
2      0 235   255    0   255
3      0   0   255   41   255
4      1   0   194  255   255
5      1  82     0  255   255
6      1 255     0  153   255
```

How can I keep my original values?
Thank a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

The color table needs integers to match against. Starting with your raster `r` and color table `coltb`, you could:

```
values(r) <- as.integer(10 * values(r))
coltb$value = as.integer(10 * coltb$value)
coltab(r) <- coltb
```

[image: raster with custom colortable]